# CSS not working with Express and EJS (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webserver, ejs

Upon entering `http://localhost:5000/` into my browser, no stylesheet works, though the favicon does, I am currently using ejs and express together in node.

I tried many fixes from other related stackoverflow 'questions' regarding this topic, but none of it seemed to work. I expected the background-color to change but was instead greeted with a white empty page and 2 errors in the console saying the following:

1. `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Internal error opening backing store for indexedDB.open. at wrappedSendMessageCallback (browser-polyfill.js:1163:16)`
2. `Refused to apply styles from 'http://localhost:5000/css/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

**My index.js:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const path = require('path')
const favicon = require('serve-favicon')
const morgan = require('morgan')

dotenv.config();

const port = process.env.PORT;

const app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('/public'))
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')))
app.use(morgan('dev'))

const homeRoute = require('./routes/homeRoute')
app.use('/', homeRoute)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`[Server]: Server is running at https://localhost:${port}`);
  });
```

**My File Structure**

```
src - My index.js file is here
├───public
│   ├───css - My CSS file is here
│   └───images
├───routes
├───sass
└───views - My home.ejs file is here
```

**My Route**

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');

const options = {root: path.join(__dirname, "../views")};

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    res.sendFile('home.ejs', options);
})

router.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/');
})

module.exports = router;
```

*Note on line 8, I set the content header to text/html because my browser was just downloading the file.*

**My EJS file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" type="text/css">
    <title>TheShiningBoots | Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for the long post hope someone can help.

Comment: Can you pls try removing `type="text/css"`

Comment: Yes, i did nothing happaned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely that Express fails to locate the `main.css` file, thus returns a default HTML 404 not found file (and you see a MIME type error in the browser).

Try replace

```
app.use(express.static('/public'))
```

With:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: Though, i would still like to know what causes the first error and how to fix it.

Comment: The first error happens in your client when failing to open IndexDB for some reason in your Browser (not related to Express). What browser are your using?

Comment: Internet explorer, there is no error with firefox and chrome